# Apache Server on Google Cloud Console VM Instance

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, apache2, google-compute-engine, lamp

I have  LAMP set up on a VM instance in Google Cloud Console. When I visit the external ip URL, I am prompted with the default Apache page shown below. I have a website application located at `/var/www/some_folder/` as oppose to the default `/var/www/html`.

I would like to be able to configure my apache server such that when I visit the website at (`http://[externalIp]`) that it launches the web application at `/var/www/some_folder/`.

How can I configure my Apache Web Server within my VM Instance in Google Cloud Console to achieve this.

Thank you,

---

Note: The web applications works fine locally.

[image]

Comment: You have the same directory twice in your question...

Answer (score 1):

The file `httpd.conf` controls most of the Apache configuration. Edit this file and look for the section `VirtualHost`. Under this section is `DocumentRoot`. Change this from `/var/www/html/` to `/var/www/some_folder/`

If you have setup SSL (HTTPS) there will be two `VirtualHost` setups. One for port 80 and another for port 443. Change both setups.

On most systems if you installed Apache with a package manager, or it came preinstalled, the Apache configuration file is located in one of these locations:

- /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
- /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
- /etc/httpd/httpd.conf
- /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf